# Prevent pasting if paste data isn't a number except when it contains $

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have an input box that has an event listener that fires on paste.

```
$("#UserInput").on('paste', function(e){

});
```

I wanted to prevent the user from pasting anything but valid numbers so 12 or 12.12 would be valid but #12 or 12.12.12 would not be. So I wrote this

```
var pasteData = '';
if(window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.getData){
   pasteData = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
   console.log('window.clipboardData');
}
else{
   pasteData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
   console.log('e.clipboardData');
}

if(isNaN(pasteData)){
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log(pasteData + ' NOT allowed');
}
else{
   console.log(pasteData + ' allowed');
}
```

And this works great. But I would also like to allow the dollar sign and commas to be pasted in as well. So $12 and $12,000 should work but $12.12.12 won't. What would be the best way to keep what existing code I have but allow pasted values that contain a single dollar sign and commas where appropriate?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227370/currency-validation

Comment: Is there some reason you don't just use a regular expression to test the input and only paste when it passes the test?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Only that I didn't think of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Currency validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227370/currency-validation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved this

```
                        $("#UserInput").on('paste', function(e){
                            var pasteData = '';
                            if(window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.getData){
                                pasteData = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
                            }
                            else{
                                pasteData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
                            }
                            var valid = /^\$?\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})*(\.\d{1,2})?$/g.test(pasteData);
                            if(!valid){
                                e.preventDefault();
                            }                                   
                        });
```

Answer (score -2):

Check that `pasteData` either doesn't start with `$`, or the rest is `NaN`.

Add `&& (!pasteData.startsWith('$') || isNaN(pasteData.slice(1)))` in here:

```
if (isNaN(pasteData) && (!pasteData.startsWith('$') || isNaN(pasteData.slice(1)))) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Lots of people also [hold this opinion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow/252531#252531)

Comment: There is no point in explaining downvotes. If i had a critique of the answer that would improve it, i would provide it.