# Validating Currency using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using a Js regular expression to validate currency of sterling pounds  (**670 , 170p ,  £17.98p , £56.90867 , 007.89p**) and should not allow the following values( **19x , 18p.12 , £p** ) but it keeps failing,,,

~ Any help will be highly appreciated

```
 var reg= /^£?[1-9]{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?$/ ;
```

Comment: try https://regex101.com/ to test your regexes.

Comment: Tried but it does not match,, any assistance on creating the regex

Comment: Are they seperated by lines or spaces?

Comment: That RegExp is not allowing `p`. Try `/^£?[1-9]{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?p?$/`.

Comment: Can you share some more samples and create a working snippet using `<>` to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: @PHPglue Am new to regexp hence need some assistance in creating it...

Comment: Have you looked into this other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227370/currency-validation

Comment: @Adriano Yah,,the cases are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest regex is :

> **£?\d+(?:\.\d+)?p?\b**

Test File: https://regex101.com/r/09wjc7/1

But it only fails with 18p.12 because it matches two groups of it. First **18p** is valid and second **12** is valid.

If you are looking it inside a text, you can add text boundaries to it, but if you are looking it by line, you can add **^**(Start of Line) and **$**(End of line) characters to the regex, which will ignore the case above.

### Explanation:

- **£?** An optional £ sign before the group
- **\d+** Required integer (one or more)
- **(?:\.\d+)?**

  - **(?:** start of non matching group
  - **\.** Dot Character
  - **\d+** Required integer (one or more)
  - **)?** Make all of this group optional
- **p?** Optional `p` character
- **\b** should end with a word boundary. https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Answer (score 0):

This should work `var regex = /^£?\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?p?$/`

```
var currencyString = '£56.78p'
regex.test(currenceString) === true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `/^£?([1-9][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?$/`

The issue with `[1-9]{1,3}` is it does not match any strings with 0, so 670 would fail to match.